# How to Add Generic Constraint to C# class which inherits from other class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am attempting to create a class with a generic constraint which inherits from another class-- I am running into a compilation error:

```
  public  class  BaseEntityController<T> where T : BaseEntity  : BaseController
    {

    }
```

This code won't compile - I get "unexpected token error". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you show us the hierarchy of what you're trying to do? Is BaseEntityController inheriting from BaseController, while BaseEntity is the constraint on T?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class BaseEntityController<T> : BaseController where T : BaseEntity
{
}
```

Comment: thanks.. I sort of realized this after I posted the question-- will mark as correct in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
public  class  BaseEntityController<T> : BaseController where T : BaseEntity
{

}
```